# prime faces DockMenu component scrolling how to fixed the position of component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

my xhtml page is:

## hai

```
    <h3>Ph.No: 804-349-4677</h3>
    </div><div>
    <p:dock position="top">
                  <p:menuitem value="Home" icon="/templates/homechange.png" url="welcome.xhtml"></p:menuitem>
                  <p:menuitem value="LogOut" icon="/templates/logout.png" url="index.xhtml"/>
                  </p:dock>

    </div>
```

tha above is header.xhtml here i scrolldown the page the component dockmenu also scrolled automatically how can i fix the position of dockmenu constantly

Answer (score 0):

With CSS, overriding the top container position rule for the dock-container-top class:

```
.ui-dock-container-top {
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

[image: primefaces showcase]

Hope it helps!

Comment: actually thats the complete code! just include it in an external css or directly in your page through a style tag in the head section.

Comment: you miss something, as you can see i've tried it on primefaces showcase and works.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <h:head>
          <title>Your page title</title>
           <style>
            .ui-dock-container-top {
                position: absolute !important;
            }
           </style>
    </h:head>

<h:body>
<h:form>
    <p:dock position="top" style="ui-dock-container-top"> 
            <p:menuitem value=...
```

Maybe a concrete example helps you. This should do the trick :)